# Advice about dual Boot Ubuntu+Windows on a HDD and SDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I currently have a 500GB HDD where I have Ubuntu installed, I've been using Ubuntu as my main OS for almost two years and I don't miss Windows at all, but I got tired of having to use Virtual Machines for Windows software so I decided to make a dual boot and I bought a 1TB SSD, and since then I've been reading opinions and stuff but I couldn't make my mind clear.

Since I have a 1TB SSD and a 500GB HDD, I thought of the following options:

1. Use the SSD for Windows and the HDD for Ubuntu
2. Use the SSD for Ubuntu and the HDD for Windows
3. Use the SSD for both Windows and Ubuntu and the HDD for files which both OS could access
4. Use the SSD for both Windows and Ubuntu and the HDD for separated files for each OS

The thing with the first one is that I already have Ubuntu in the HDD with no problems, and half of the HDD space left, so it seems easier to just install Windows in the new SSD, repair the grub (That's what I found I should do [here](https://silentinfotech.com/blog/steps-to-install-windows-10-on-existing-ubuntu-16-04/)) and that's it. But then I read that Ubuntu would be improved from having it in the SSD, and since I want to keep it as my main OS, I thought in the second.

The second sounds great, and it seems that it is not much different from the first, but I could migrate Ubuntu to the SSD first (I found information [here](https://frankfzw.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/migrate-ubuntu-14-04-from-hdd-to-ssd/)) and then install Windows and repair grub. The thing is that Ubuntu, as far as I know, is lighter and faster than Windows and if I stay with Windows in the HDD it would perform worst than Ubuntu would do in the same HDD, right?

I thought of the third and fourth option then, to stick with both OS in the SSD and keep the files in the HDD, but then I wonder, I could make the two OS share files so I wouldn't have to send them to myself from one OS to the other (I found information [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/)) but it seems that I would have to say goodbye to the filesystem that ubuntu uses, and since I like it as it is, I thought I better not, so that leads us to the fourth option.

But then I wonder if it would be significantly harder to have both OS in half of each drive, for example, if it would be harder to install them, or if I want to change the HDD in the future, or for future changes in my OS, and also I read sometimes it happens that after a Windows Update you couldn't boot into Ubuntu. Also, that way I would have to install Ubuntu all over again, and a little remark here, even though I have been using Ubuntu for a while, I didn't install it myself and it seems that Ubuntu installation is considerably harder than the Windows one (and since I already have Ubuntu installed and working, I really don't want to mess that up).

In summary, I think I got between options 2 and 4, but I would like to have further advice on stuff I didn't consider, stuff I understood wrong, or some recommendations before I start to mess things up instead of after I messed them up.

Btw, I did already back up my files but not the entire OS, I figured that I could clean install it if things went wrong.

Comment: You can do any of them, and this is opinion based, so probably will get closed. You can use NTFS for a shared data partition, if Windows fast start up is off. UEFI or BIOS system? IF UEFI, make sure drives are gpt partitioned. Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs or repairs, for both Ubuntu & Windows, so just be consistent. I suggest operating systems on SSD with maybe some data, and some data and backups of SSD data on HDD.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Pay attention to what oldfred says about both OS booting in same mode. Windows needs SSD more than Ubuntu and must be put on a disk first. Ubuntu runs mainly in RAM, (If you have enough RAM). It is mainly boot and save speed that are at stake. I would install Windows on the SSD in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Ubuntu is installed in. (Because I am Lazy).

Comment: What ever you decide you will want to share files between Windows and Ubuntu but that doesn’t mean you have to stop using you existing Linux filesystem. Just create an additional partition formatted in NTFS or exFAT and use that for shared files